# Smartcard reader naming

Tags: c#, smartcard, smartcard-reader, pcsc, winscard

I have two readers (HID OMNIKEY 5321) in system (every reader performs a different function)

- reader 1 - "Smart Card Reader **0**"
- reader 2 - "Smart Card Reader **1**"

In my program is set up that

- "Smart Card Reader **0**" - action 1
- "Smart Card Reader **1**" - action 2

but sometimes (without rebooting, perhaps lost contact)

- reader 1 gets name "Smart Card Reader **1**"
- reader 2 gets name "Smart Card Reader **0**"

and the program does not do what users need.
I use SCardGetStatusChange (requires the name of the reader) in WinScard.dll

**What to do?
Is there a way to change the name of the reader (firmware, drivers...)? 
Is it possible to use the serial number of the reader?**

*I also looked, but no result
[Smartcard reader naming: when removing any reader, the name of the rest changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636055/smartcard-reader-naming-when-removing-any-reader-the-name-of-the-rest-changes)
[How are PCSC smart card reader 'friendly names' constructed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813041/how-are-pcsc-smart-card-reader-friendly-names-constructed)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found a solution [Getting PCSC reader serial number with WinSCard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940824/getting-pcsc-reader-serial-number-with-winscard)

serial number reader

```
...
SCardConnect(hContext, readerName, SCARD_SHARE_DIRECT, SCARD_PROTOCOL_UNDEFINED, ref hCard, ref protocol);
SCardGetAttrib(hCard, SCARD_ATTR_VENDOR_IFD_SERIAL_NO, receiveBuffer, ref receivebufferLen);
...
```

Comment: Would have been nice if you had included the variable declarations so we know what you are sending and expecting back. I have an idea but don't want to get it wrong.

Comment: Thank you for posting it, @Yuriy -- just used it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should focus on the smartcard inserted in / connected to the reader rather than the reader itself and use card specific information (i.e. serial number or label) to choose the correct reader.

Comment: My application is designed for wakeboarding cable park. Each client has one card. action 1 - electronic queue, action 2 - start/stop

Comment: Different location. Reader 1 - starting area. Reader 2 - front of the screen (electronic queue)